# TypeError: Model 'project.forecast' does not exist in registry odoo14

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12, odoo-14

I'm migrating an Enterprise Odoo 12 module to 14 which depends on the project module, when I'm trying to install I get this error:

```
TypeError: Model 'project.forecast' does not exist in registry.
```

I've been trying to locate the model definition but I couldn't find it in the code

I [stumble upon some similar error](https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/typeerror-model-project-task-does-not-exist-in-registry-error-143920) and the answer was to include the dependency to the manifest, the manifest is the following:

```
'depends': ['base','project','project_forecast','hr_timesheet','hr_expense','account_reports','sale_timesheet','documents','hr_holidays','calendar','contacts']
```

I see there, `project_forecast`, so I bet something has changed in 14 and I'm not aware of the change.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I found something, may be useful for you: `That's what happens when you change the installable = False to force a non migrated module to be in the module list`

Comment: can you put the link of the resource? thanks

Comment: https://acysos.dyndns.org/oca/hr/issues/395

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there has been a huge rewrite in the project module, now project forecast has been mutated to a class named planning shift as follows:

```
class PlanningShift(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'planning.slot'
```

Any inheritance you do on **project forecast** model has to be changed to planning.slot